# Android Client and Google App Engine APIs

Tags: java, android, python, google-app-engine

Am I confused as to what is possible between an Android Client and Google App Engine? I would like to be able to create a Python API that would handle requests between GAE services such as Datastore, and an Android Client.

I have found some examples that detail how to make a call from within an Android Client, but it doesn't seem to outline whether or not you can pass data to any specific API language. **The question I have is whether or not it is possible to use a Python API deployed on GAE and making calls through Google End Points, or would I have to use Java Servlets to handle requests?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Python to do what you want.

Google designs their services (such as GAE and endpoints) to be language agnostic, e.g. using JSON to serialize objects.

There are a few advantages to using Java on both, such as being able to share code between client and service projects, but Google does not promote such dependencies at all - you will have no problem using Python instead.